# How to stop sagemaker charges when we need to temporarily shut down the sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I need to temporarily shut down the sagemaker that I am using for my models. I need to stop the charges so that I can have my model, artifacts, endpoint configuration saved and delete just that particular data that is easier to again activate the endpoint.

After going through the needed documentations I deleted the endpoints which were active.

I monitored the charges after deleting the endpoints but the charges are still adding up, it's lesser than before but am not sure what exactly is costing me in amazon sagemaker.

Isn't it the case that when we delete endpoints the charges are stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can see broken down cost and usage by using the Cost Explorer (https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/home#/cost-explorer), and identify what types of resources are still remaining.

1. visit the Billing and Cost Management > Cost Explorer
2. Choose Date Range, Granularity (Daily), and Dimension (Usage type), and apply filter by Service (SageMaker).
3. Check the "Cost and usage breakdown" section.